# One line if statement in Ruby

Tags: ruby, if-statement, branch

I have following piece of code:

```
if day > 31 
  day -= 31 
  month = "April"
end
```

Can I write it in one line different than:

```
if day > 31 then day -= 31 and month = "April" end
```

?

I've tried it like:

```
if day > 31 {day -= 31; month = "April"}
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: if day > 31 then day -= 31; month = "April" end

Comment: The expression separator is `;` not `and`. `and` is a boolean operator. What made you think it was an expression separator?

Comment: You *can* put it on one line, but it results in code that is less readable. It won't run faster so why do it if it makes the code harder to understand? If I ran into that in a code review there'd be a lecture on writing maintainable code and an instant code change.

Comment: In this specific case the goal was to write code as tight as possible. I was just exploring

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
(day -= 31; month = "April") if day > 31
```

Alternate way (As suggested by @mudasobwa in comments below) :

```
day, month = day - 31, "April" if day > 31
```

Comment: basically yeah. In ruby one line if statement is `statement if condition`

Comment: Or, without brackets: `day, month = day - 31, "April" if day > 31`.

Comment: @mudasobwa  +1 for that. I actually tried doing it first, but somewhere i did it wrong. Thanks for the example. :)