# Ruby chaining methods with if-statement

Tags: ruby, methods, chaining

I have the following:

```
def method(integer)  
  a = 3+integer
  a += 10 if "one"<"another"
end
```

Can I write it in one line somehow with chaining methods?

Something like `a = 3+f += 10 if "one"<"another"`?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Also, this is not what method chaining is.

Comment: Actually I shouldn't wrap it in a method coz its a part of a formula but I felt it would be more natural for this example.

Comment: Yes, now I see this case is not about chaining

Comment: Don't create multiple questions asking the same thing. (http://stackoverflow.com/q/27166803/128421). The difference between these two is marginal, and the answers to the first one should have been sufficient to answer this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `and` or `&&` both use [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), you could use:

```
(a = 3+integer) and ("one"<"another") and  (a += 10)
```

It says in '[Using “and” and “or” in Ruby](http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/)':

> *and* is useful for chaining related operations together until one of them returns nil or false
>
> Another way of thinking about *and* is as a reversed if statement modifier

Comment: This fit the purpose for my task. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could do it in one line using the ternary operator:

```
def method(integer)  
  a = integer + ("one"<"another" ? 13 : 3)
end
```

Make sure you don't hurt the readability of the code when you do that, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
a= 3+ integer + ("one"<"another" ? 10 : 0)
```

`3+ integer` will add `3` to `integer` value and `("one"<"another" ? 10 : 0)` will return 10 if condition is true otherwise will return 0.

Comment: Don't enter only code. Take time to explain why it should be used. Throwing out code is akin to throwing someone a fish. Explaining it is teaching them how to fish, which helps them avoid the problem the next time.